# How to insert values into a table with default values from a select query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, insert, json, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to `INSERT` values into a PostgreSQL table from a `SELECT` statement and to use `DEFAULT` values for the columns that are null?

In my case, the `SELECT` statement is selecting from JSON.

In the attempts below, I was successful by explicitly retrieving the sequence but I am hoping there is a way to either INSERT using the DEFAULT values. Or select DEFAULT values without having to call the default functions explicitly.

```
-- Example table
create table animals
(
    id serial,
    nm character varying (30) NOT NULL, --name
    typ character varying(10),
    tvi integer,
    tvf numeric(8,3)
);


insert into animals VALUES (DEFAULT,'mouse','m',4,12.45);

select row_to_json(a) from animals a;

select * from json_populate_record(null::animals,'{"id":null,"nm":"mouse","typ":"m","tvi":4,"tvf":12.450}');

--All good.


-- Attempt #1
INSERT INTO animals
select id ,nm,typ,tvi,tvf from json_populate_record(null::animals,'{"id":null,"nm":"mouse","typ":"m","tvi":4,"tvf":12.450}');

/*
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, mouse, m, 4, 12.450).
********** Error **********

ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, mouse, m, 4, 12.450).
*/


-- Attempt #2
INSERT INTO animals
select DEFAULT,nm,typ,tvi,tvf from json_populate_record(null::animals,'{"id":null,"nm":"mouse","typ":"m","tvi":4,"tvf":12.450}');

/*  I didn't  expect this to work, but it does illustrate what I am trying to accomplish
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
LINE 2: select DEFAULT,nm,typ,tvi,tvf from json_populate_record(null...
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 28

*/


-- Attempt #3
INSERT INTO animals
select nextval('animals_id_seq'::regclass),nm,typ,tvi,tvf from json_populate_record(null::animals,'{"id":null,"nm":"mouse","typ":"m","tvi":4,"tvf":12.450}');

/*  This works, but I'm hoping for a way to accomplish this without knowing the underlying functions generating the default values.
Query returned successfully: one row affected, 11 msec execution time.
*/

select version();  --'PostgreSQL 9.5.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add all ColumnsNames (exclude the 'id' Column) after the Tablename, there will be Insert the serial automaticly like:

```
INSERT INTO animals(nm,typ,tvi,tvf) select nm,typ,tvi,tvf from json_po.....
```

You can also add a [DEFAULT Value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html) in your Column, to set a Default Value if the column is not in the Insert Column-list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more than one record :

```
insert into animals(nm,typ,tvi,tvf) 
select nm,typ,tvi,tvf 
from json_populate_recordset(null::animals, 
'
[
 {"nm":"mouse","typ":"m","tvi":4,"tvf":12.450},
 {"nm":"dog","typ":"x","tvi":10,"tvf":13.450}
]
');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of related. I found it useful when all the columns have defaults.

```
drop schema if exists Working cascade;
create schema Working;
create table if not exists Working.postgresDateTesting
(
    ts1 timestamptz not null default now(),
    ts2 timestamptz not null default now(),
    ts3 timestamptz not null default now()
);

insert into Working.postgresDateTesting select;

select * from Working.postgresDateTesting;
```